# 20 million unique codes in mySQL - what length should the codes be?

Tags: mysql, unique

I need to generate 20 million unique codes for storing in mySQL. The code string should be alphanumeric minus ambiguous chars (0,1,O,L,I,S,5) so total available chars are 29. How long should the string be in order to accommodate 20 million unique codes?

Also, can anyone help with creating a mySQL procedure that would generate and insert the codes maintaining uniqueness?

**UPDATE**: The codes generated cannot be sequential to avoid incremental brute force attempts so for example only 1 in 100 of sequential codes should be used.

Thank you!!

Comment: 5 chars. But why would you do this?

Comment: I just wanted to the know the minimum length and was hoping it wouldn't be more than 8.

Comment: If you are using this a lot, to stress test applications, you should consider getting something like [ems mysql data generator](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mysql/datagenerator)

Comment: This is basic maths question more than mysql / unique question. If you have 29 possible characters, then 2 characters will yield 29 * 29 possible combinations. Same goes on for 3 (29 * 29 * 29) and so on. This is how you can resolve such questions on your own. I'm going to close vote this because there's no programming problem here to be solved.

Comment: NB, basic maths to you perhaps. Also if you read on there is a programming question here as I'd like to know how to programatically create and insert the codes into mySQL.

Comment: aconrad, no this will be one off to generate codes for an SMS promo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five characters is sufficient: 29 ^ 5 > 2 * 10 ^ 7.

In other words, there are 20511149 possible strings you can make out of 5 characters with a 29 character alphabet. As this is more than 20 million you'll only need 5 characters to produce 20 million unique strings.

I'm not sure a MySQL function exists to generate unique strings given certain contraints but you could write a function for this in your application. If you know the current number of records then you also know what the next unique string will be that you need to produce.

Comment: Note that assuming the goal here is some sort of unique codes that aren't trivially guessable, using 5 characters would be a horrible idea since nearly any random 5 characters someone guessed would be valid; the odds of guessing correctly would be about 98%.

Comment: I was thinking of an 8 char code which would be easy to read and type (it's for an SMS promo) but will provide enough wiggle room for guessed codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the codes as numbers in base 29. So for `N` codes, you will need `ceil(log(N))`, except that the `log` should be in base `29`. So in this case it will be `5`.

To generate those IDs of yours that you need, you can have a function which converts a number from base 10, to base 29, using the characters you have available. This task is straight forward using standard methods like [this](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1104/number_conversion/convexp.html).

You can of course have also the reverse function which converts the number in base 29 to a decimal. In fact, you might even not need to generate those numbers in base 29 once you have both these functions.

Comment: Thanks but that link confuses me more than before!